# What is the best way to POST back non-input data for nested objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I am using MVC Post/Redirect/Get Pattern. The model has a list property named "Products" and each item of it has another list property named "Images". The problem is in POST method all non-input fields are null. I have tried to add hidden fields and it works fine for "Products" but it's not working for "Images". Anyway, is adding hidden field the only solution to this? Isn't there a way to force posting back all data sent at first place?
This is the model definition:

```
public class ProductRequestMessage
{
    //...
    public List<ProductRequestEntry> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRequestEntry
{
    //...
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    //...
    public List<ImageData> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImageData
{
    //...
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the problem of the Model. Html form will only post-back the input and hidden fields.

Also it is not a good practice to retain data by post-back. Instead you should post back the Ids and retrieve the data on the server side. Then merge the retried data and posted data to construct your model.

This will also reduce the size of the post back and make the application work faster.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that posting back unchanged data is not a good practice because of the security issues and bandwidth considerations. But, not doing that impose additional operation on database which is not desirable in some situations. By the way, the post back data do not include "Images" property even though that there are hidden fields for "ProductRequestMessage.Products.Images" and also for each "ProductRequestMessage.Products.Images[i]".